# Is it possible to implement an action sheet without blur effect?

Tags: ios, swift

I have use action sheet to implement color selection

```
let alertAlertController = AlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
self.alertAlertController = alertAlertController

let alertVisualStyle = AlertVisualStyle(alertStyle: .actionSheet)
alertVisualStyle.blurEffect = nil

alertVisualStyle.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
alertAlertController.visualStyle = alertVisualStyle
```

It looks as following. If you pay attention, whenever the action sheet appears, there will be a slight blur effect

[image]

However, I was wondering, is it possible to avoid the blur effect?

Reason is that, I plan to implement font selection feature. Without the blur effect, I was able to let user to visualize the "after changing font effect" in real-time manner.

This is an app example, which implement the font selection in action sheet liked UI, and without blur effect. User can visualize the font effect in real-time manner.

[image]

Does anyone has any idea, how can we implement an action sheet, or action sheet liked UI, without the blur effect?

Thanks.

Comment: A sheet yes. Action sheet I don’t think so

Comment: Don’t use a UIAlertController. Use a UISheetViewController.

Comment: Consider adding your view as a subview, instead of *presenting* a controller?