# UISheetPresentationController: Remove Dim Background but Keep Touch-to-Dismiss?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using the UISheetPresentationController to present a view, as shown in the following code:

```
@IBAction func click(_ sender: Any) {
    let whiteViewController = WhiteViewController.instanceFromMainStoryBoard()
    
    if let sheet = whiteViewController.sheetPresentationController {
        sheet.detents = [.medium()]
        
        sheet.prefersScrollingExpandsWhenScrolledToEdge = false
        
        sheet.prefersGrabberVisible = false
        
        // Remove dim effect.
        ////sheet.largestUndimmedDetentIdentifier = .medium
    }
    
    self.present(whiteViewController, animated: true)
}
```

The outcome is as follow

[image]

This code results in a presentation with:

1. A dimmed background.
2. A 'Touch anywhere to dismiss' behavior.

---

However, I want to remove the dim background while keeping the 'Touch anywhere to dismiss' functionality. When I add the line:

```
sheet.largestUndimmedDetentIdentifier = .medium
```

The dim background is indeed removed, but the touch-to-dismiss behavior is gone too, as illustrated:

[image]

Is there a way to achieve both – removing the dim background and retaining the touch-to-dismiss functionality?

Thank you.

Comment: Like your previous question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77250902/is-it-possible-to-implement-an-action-sheet-without-blur-effect - consider using a subview instead of presenting a controller? https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzlps.gif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to handle touches outside the sheet yourself. Once you remove the dim, there is no dimming view that the sheet controls, so the sheet doesn't know about touches outside it.

A simple way is to just add a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to the view that presents the sheet. e.g.

```
let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapped))
view.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
gesture.cancelsTouchesInView = false
```

```
@objc func tapped() {
    presentedViewController?.dismiss(animated: true)
}
```